# Why does (nil . nil) evaluate to (nil) instead of just nil in SBCL?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

In the SBCL REPL, why does entering `'(nil . nil)` evaluate to `(nil)` and not just `nil`?

If an empty list is one where both "elements" of the cons cell are `nil`, why are these not the same?

My assumption for this is that SBCL makes the following evaluations:

```
(car '()) => nil
(cdr '()) => nil
(car '(nil . nil)) => nil
(cdr '(nil . nil)) => nil
```

And yet:

```
'() => nil
'(nil . nil) => (nil)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If an empty list is one where both "elements" of the cons cell are
> nil,

That is not the case.  The empty list, `()`, is just a different way to spell NIL, and NIL does not have a CONS cell, rather it is a symbol, similar to EAT and X.

[Common Lisp the Language, 2nd Edition, 6.1. Logical Values](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node70.html):

> The names nil and t are constants in Common Lisp. Although they are
> symbols like any other symbols, and appear to be treated as variables
> when evaluated, it is not permitted to modify their values. See
> defconstant.
>
> **[Constant] nil**
>
> The value of nil is always nil. This object represents the logical
> false value and also the empty list. ***It can also be written ()***.

And, from [Practical Common Lisp, 4. Syntax and Semantics](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics):

> This equivalence between NIL and the empty list is built into the
> reader: if the reader sees (), it reads it as the symbol NIL.

Therefore, the empty list is not a list at all! Now, about this:

```
(car '()) => nil
(cdr '()) => nil
```

Because the empty list is not a list, it doesn't have a CONS cell, yet `CAR` and `CDR` are used to peer into a CONS cell--except in one special case: CAR and CDR [are defined to return NIL for an empty list](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_c.htm#car).  The result of that special case is that you can't use CAR and CDR to distinguish between the empty list, `()`, and the list `(nil)`:

```
* (defvar *x* (list nil))
*X*
* *x*
(NIL)
* (car *x*)
NIL
* (cdr *x*)
NIL

* (setf *x* NIL)
NIL
* *x*
NIL
* (car *x*)
NIL
* (cdr *x*)
NIL
```

Because the empty list, `()`, is just another way to spell NIL, the previous paragraph could be rewritten as:

> Because NIL is not a list, it doesn't have a CONS cell, yet CAR and
> CDR are used to peer into a CONS cell--except in one special case: CAR
> and CDR are defined to return NIL for NIL. That means you can't use
> CAR and CDR to distinguish between NIL and the list `(nil)`.

======

[Dotted Lists](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node28.html)

> A dotted list is one whose last cons does not have nil for its cdr,
> rather some other data object...Such a
> list is called "dotted" because of the special notation used for it:
> the elements of the list are written between parentheses as before,
> but after the last element and before the right parenthesis are
> written a dot (surrounded by blank space) and then the cdr of the last
> cons. As a special case, a single cons is notated by writing the car
> and the cdr between parentheses and separated by a space-surrounded
> dot. For example:
>
> ```
> (a . 4)         ;A cons whose car is a symbol 
>                 ; and whose cdr is an integer 
> (a b c . d)     ;A dotted list with three elements whose last cons 
>                 ; has the symbol d in its cdr
> ```

A list containing the single integer 9 looks like this:

```
      CONS cell
+---------+--------+ 
|  CAR    |  CDR   | 
|   *     |   *----+---> nil
+---|-----+--------+
    |
    V
    9
```

In `list syntax`, that is written as:

```
(9)
```

In `dotted list notation`, that is written as:

```
(9 . nil)
```

`Dotted list notation` explicitly states both the CAR and the CDR of an element in the list.  With the `list syntax`, a CDR pointing to NIL is implicit for the last element of the list.

Compare `(nil . nil)` to `(9 . nil)`: `(9 . nil)` is a list with one element `9`, which similarly means that `(nil . nil)` must be a list with one element  `nil`:

```
  |
  V
( 9  . nil)  --> (9)
(nil . nil)  --> (nil)
  ^
  |
```

Drawing the CONS cell for `(nil . nil)`:

```
      CONS cell
+---------+--------+ 
|  CAR    |  CDR   | 
|   *     |   *----+---> nil
+---|-----+--------+
    |
    V
   nil
```

Compare that to the drawing of the CONS cell for the list `(9)` above.  In both cases, list syntax puts parens around the CAR.

Comment: For what it's worth, those are Emacs Lisp citations, while the OP's language is Common Lisp. In this case, everything you've said applies to both, since Emacs Lisp is heavily inspired by Common Lisp, but they are still different languages.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, I replaced with links to *Common Lisp the Language, 2nd Edition*.

Answer (score 7):

`car` and `cdr` return `nil` if given `nil` as an argument. Let's predispose of the word `nil` for a minute and see what values you're *actually* looking at.

```
(car '()) == '()
(cdr '()) => nil
```

`car` and `cdr` got an empty list, so we return `nil`, or `()`.

```
(car '(nil . nil)) => nil
(cdr '(nil . nil)) => nil
```

Now, `(nil . nil)` is `(() . ())`. That is, it's a cons cell whose car and cdr are both `nil`.

When we have a `. ()` at the end of a cons cell, we can shorten it notationally by omitting the trailing `nil`. This is just a notational convenience, so by our notation `(() . ())` can be written as `(())`, or `(nil)`. Note that that does *not* change the value. The most explicit way to write it is still `(() . ())`, but we can also write it shorter for readability.

> If an empty list is one where both "elements" of the cons cell are nil, why are these not the same?

That is not correct. An empty list is *not* a cons cell at all. An empty list is the atom `nil`. It's a symbol, just like `'foo` or `'pizza` or `'common-lisp`. It's just a symbol that we chose to use for this purpose. But `nil` doesn't *have* a car or cdr cell. It just so happens that it's often convenient to let `(car nil)` and `(cdr nil)` be `nil` as corner cases of algorithms, so the *functions* `car` and `cdr` have special behavior on `nil`. But `nil` is *not* a cons cell.

```
> (consp nil)
nil
> (consp '())
nil
> (consp '(1 . 2))
T
```

Per the [system class `LIST`](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_list.htm#list), the `list` type can be described as

> The types `cons` and `null` form an exhaustive partition of the type list.

So a *list* in Common Lisp is defined to be "either a cons cell or the special value `nil`". Notably, `nil` is not itself a cons cell.

Answer (score 4):

That's not SBCL specific. It's defined in the Common Lisp standard.

**NILs in a cons cell**

Note that `NIL` and `()` are the *same object*, just written differently:

```
CL-USER 33 > (eq 'nil '())
T
```

Note also that you don't evaluate `(nil . nil)`, but `'(nil . nil)`. The former is not valid Lisp code. The latter is, because it is a quoted syntactically correct s-expression.

`(nil . nil)` is equal to `(nil)`, but differently written. The cons structure is *equal*.

Above s-expressions are **equal**:

```
CL-USER 34 > (equal '(nil . nil) '(nil))
T
```

**CAR and C****R of NIL**

All *cxxxxr* operations of Common Lisp are defined to return `NIL`, when called with an empty list (-> the symbol/list `NIL`):

```
CL-USER 35 > (car 'nil)
NIL

CL-USER 36 > (car '())
NIL

CL-USER 37 > (caddar 'nil)
NIL
```

See [Accessor CAR, CDR, CAAR, CADR, CDAR, CDDR, CAAAR, CAADR, CADAR, CADDR, CDAAR, CDADR, CDDAR, CDDDR, CAAAAR, CAAADR, CAADAR, CAADDR, CADAAR, CADADR, CADDAR, CADDDR, CDAAAR, CDAADR, CDADAR, CDADDR, CDDAAR, CDDADR, CDDDAR, CDDDDR](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm) in the Common Lisp standard.

> `car x` => *object*

> If *x* is a *cons*, `car` returns the *car* of that *cons*. If *x* is `nil`, *car* returns `nil`.

**Differences of the function `car` between languages Common Lisp and Scheme**

That's different from the programming language Scheme, where `(car '())` is an error. See for example [R7RS small, car](https://standards.scheme.org/corrected-r7rs/r7rs-Z-H-8.html#TAG:__tex2page_index_540).

> Note that it is an error to take the *car* of the empty list.

Also note that *Scheme* does not have `nil`. It's undefined in the language and thus not the same as the *empty list* `()`. Evaluating an *empty list* `()` in Scheme is an error.

The following *Scheme* expressions evaluate to an error:

```
(car ())       ; evaluating the empty list is an error in Scheme
(car '())      ; car of an empty list is an error in Scheme
(car 'nil)     ; car of the symbol nil is an error in Scheme
```

The three above expression will evaluate to `NIL` in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 2):

The critical mistake you have made here is to get an implication the wrong way around.  In particular, in Common Lisp it is true that `car` and `cdr` of the empty list return the empty list, but it is *not* true that any object for which that is true is the empty list.  Indeed, it's clear that this can't be true because the empty list object is unique, while `(eq (cons '() '()) (cons '() '()))` must be false.

So while 'being the empty list' implies (in Common Lisp!) that taking the `car` / `cdr` returns the empty list, the converse is not true.

Answer (score 0):

`'(1 2 3)` can being written in dot notation as `'(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))` or equivalently `'(1 . (2 . (3 . NIL)))` since, as the you mention, `() => NIL`.

then, noting `'(1 2 3) == '(1 . (2 3))` , it's no surprise that `'(2 3) == '(2 . (3 . ()))` ; and `'(2 3) == '(2 . (3))` thus `'(3) == '(3 . ())` ; and `'() == '()`.